# How to convert a raster image to vector shapefile in qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, openstreetmap, vectorization

[image]

Please show the detailed conversion process.

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Your question seem like you don't have much experience with GIS.  Please familiarise yourself with the beginners tour so you know how to ask effective questions.  Additional information would be greatly appreciated in what you are trying to achieve.  Check out this link to the QGIS training on digitising: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/stands_digitazing.html?highlight=digitize

Comment: Can you please tell us the raster format? ?(tiff,jpeg,png etc) would be helpful.

Comment: came to this sub to ask this question. the question is clear to me, and @gisnside answered it. if i had the juice, i'd vote for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments by @Knightshound, you seem to lack some experience in GIS. Still, i'm going to answer your question so you get some of this experience you need.

What you want to do is Polygonize, in the Raster menu/Conversion/Polygonize (Raster to Vector), but you'll quickly realize it doesn't produce what you expect ;)

[image]

Comment: Of course, i strongly recommend @DPSSpatial answer, vectorizing this image automatically is just a loss of time :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than converting that image to vector, you should get the OpenStreetMap data from Mapzen:

https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/metro/kolkata_india/

Bring that into QGIS and check out what data is there, and then start to style it as your raster map is styled.